# Automatic backup of folder

Tags: backup

I have one particular folder on my linux box that I would like to have fully backed up and be able to "go back in time" on a file and see all previous revisions.

To add complications, this folder is shared (with the inbuilt sharing tools) and is accessed and written to by a Windows machine. For this reason, I'd like the backup to be written to a place where the windows machine does not have access.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 8):

Well I use the following script for my backup:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Gets date of most recent backup.    
newestfile=$(cd /home/<USERNAME>/.Backups && find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" ")        
budate=`echo $newestfile| cut -c10-19`

# Gets current date

cdate=$(date --iso)

# If the cureent date is the same as the date of the most recent backup, don't run the backup, just give a notification that says it has already been done today.

if [ $cdate = $budate ]; then
    echo "Backup Complete"
    notify-send -i /home/<USERNAME>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Already started/finished backup for today."

# If the dates are different, start the backup.

else
    echo "Starting backup"
    notify-send -i /home/<USERNAME>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Starting backup for today."
# Compresses the files into .tar.gz format 

    tar -cvpzf /home/<USERNAME>/.Backups/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M).tar.gz "/home/<USERNAME>/folder/to/back/up" --exclude=.Backups && notify-send --expire-time=60000 -i /home/tim/Pictures/Home/Logos/safe.png 'Backup Status' 'Finished backup for today.'
fi
```

This will save a backup file that looks like this:

```
backup-2014-07-26-13:13.tar.gz
```

In the hidden folder `/home/<USERNAME>/.Backups`

The safe.png file that it used for the notifications can be downloaded [from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIGke.png).

1. Save the script in `/home/<USERNAME>/Scripts` as `backup.sh`
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   chmod +x Scripts/backup.sh
   mkdir .Backups
   touch .Backups/backup-2000-01-01-00:00.tar.gz
   ```
3. Then add the command `Scripts/./backup.sh` to the start at login applications. Even if you login more than one time in a day, you only get 1 backup.

   **OR**

   You could also use cron to run the script regularly. Edit it using `crontab -e` and add this line to the end:

   ```
   0 15 * * *    bash /path/to/script/backup.sh
   ```

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: You could also use cron to execute it hourly, daily or weekly, depending on your needs. In this example, the script is executed daily at 3pm: Launch crontab via `crontab -e` and add the following line to the end `0 15 * * *    bash /path/to/script/backup.sh`

Comment: @jnuk Thank's, I never have understood cron enough to use it in an answer.

Comment: It's actually pretty simple. There are even [generators](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php) for it.

Comment: @jnuk Cool! That makes it easier!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I chose in the end was something called "Back In Time". I set the backup interval to 5 minutes and it backs up my specific folders to another location and allows me to go back through the snapshots it takes.

http://backintime.le-web.org/

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and looked for GUI backup utilities that support at least Linux (they tended to be cross-platform). I also wanted good automation/interval capabilities. These are my 3 top picks, from what I read of reviews and can tell from intuition, all untested:

1. [Back In Time](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime) (See [documentation](https://backintime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for screenshots)
2. [fwbackups](http://www.diffingo.com/oss/fwbackups/screenshots)
3. [grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/screenshot.html) (GUI for rsync)

Hopefully that helps save others some time. There are a lot of backup utilities out there, but few with solid-looking GUI's for Linux that seemed to be modern.

Honorable mention: [Duplicati](https://www.duplicati.com/screenshots/), though I've used it before on Windows and I wasn't very fond of its instability. My backups were getting corrupted or glitchy. Maybe in the long run they will fix these issues.